# Genexus QueryViewer

Tags: java, tomcat, genexus

I have the following runtime error. This happens when I run a web panel that contains a queryviewer.

- The project is deployed on a Tomcat 8 server.
- The database is SQLServer 2011
- Genexus 16 (Upgrade 11)

  *Error: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL statement or JDBC escape, terminating '"' not found. at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLParser.parse(SQLParser.java:1155) at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLParser.parse(SQLParser.java:156) at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:104) at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.prepareStatement(ConnectionJDBC2.java:2221) at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.prepareStatement(ConnectionJDBC2.java:2179) at com.genexus.db.driver.GXConnection.prepareStatement(GXConnection.java:882) at com.genexus.db.driver.PreparedStatementCache.createStatement(PreparedStatementCache.java:77) at com.genexus.db.driver.PreparedStatementCache.getStatement(PreparedStatementCache.java:120) at com.genexus.db.driver.GXConnection.getStatement(GXConnection.java:789) at com.genexus.db.driver.GXConnection.getStatement(GXConnection.java:801) at com.genexus.db.SentenceProvider.getPreparedStatement(SentenceProvider.java:16) at com.genexus.db.ForEachCursor.preExecute(ForEachCursor.java:159) at com.genexus.db.DataStoreProvider.execute(DataStoreProvider.java:233) at com.genexus.db.DataStoreProvider.execute(DataStoreProvider.java:204) at qviewer.services.gxpl_DBAccess.ExecuteSQL(gxpl_DBAccess.java:95) at qviewer.services.gxpl_DBAccess.ExecuteSQL(gxpl_DBAccess.java:225) at qviewer.services.Sdtgxpl_DBAccess.executesql(Sdtgxpl_DBAccess.java:67) at qviewer.services.data.recordset.gxpl_getrecordsetquery.privateExecute(gxpl_getrecordsetquery.java:101) at qviewer.services.data.recordset.gxpl_getrecordsetquery.execute_int(gxpl_getrecordsetquery.java:75) at qviewer.services.data.recordset.gxpl_getrecordsetquery.execute(gxpl_getrecordsetquery.java:55) at qviewer.services.data.recordset.gxpl_getrecordset.privateExecute(gxpl_getrecordset.java:166) at qviewer.services.data.recordset.gxpl_getrecordset.execute_int(gxpl_getrecordset.java:112) at qviewer.services.data.recordset.gxpl_getrecordset.execute(gxpl_getrecordset.java:77) at qviewer.services.gxpl_getrecordsetpagedata.privateExecute(gxpl_getrecordsetpagedata.java:179) at qviewer.services.gxpl_getrecordsetpagedata.execute_int(gxpl_getrecordsetpagedata.java:162) at qviewer.services.gxpl_getrecordsetpagedata.execute(gxpl_getrecordsetpagedata.java:107) at qviewer.services.gxpl_getpagedatafortable_logic.privateExecute(gxpl_getpagedatafortable_logic.java:105) at qviewer.services.gxpl_getpagedatafortable_logic.execute_int(gxpl_getpagedatafortable_logic.java:83) at qviewer.services.gxpl_getpagedatafortable_logic.execute(gxpl_getpagedatafortable_logic.java:60) at qviewer.services.gxpl_getpagedatafortable.privateExecute(gxpl_getpagedatafortable.java:71) at qviewer.services.gxpl_getpagedatafortable.execute_int(gxpl_getpagedatafortable.java:52) at qviewer.services.gxpl_getpagedatafortable.execute(gxpl_getpagedatafortable.java:35) at qviewer.services.gxpl_get_main.privateExecute(gxpl_get_main.java:88) at qviewer.services.gxpl_get_main.execute_int(gxpl_get_main.java:52) at qviewer.services.gxpl_get_main.execute(gxpl_get_main.java:35) at qviewer.services.agxpl_get_impl.privateExecute(agxpl_get_impl.java:53) at qviewer.services.agxpl_get_impl.webExecute(agxpl_get_impl.java:43) at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectBase.doExecute(GXWebObjectBase.java:218) at qviewer.services.agxpl_get.doExecute(agxpl_get.java:22) at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callDoExecute(GXWebObjectStub.java:242) at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(GXWebObjectStub.java:124) at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.doPost(GXWebObjectStub.java:40) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at com.genexus.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with a Linux implementation, don't know if it's your case but here is what I found: it turns that the XML files "com.app.QueryViewerObjects.xml", "com.app.QueryViewerQueries.xml" and "com.app.QueryViewerSecurity.xml" had the [BOM mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Once removed the mark, the QV worked like a charm.

There could be another reason for this error and has to do with the lifetime of the KB. Sometimes an upgrade or a new version of Genexus comes with new versions of JARs, and sometimes comes with the exact same JAR BUT with the names with uppercases instead of lowercases as previous versions. In Windows there is no problem because the JAR are overwritten, but in Linux nope. So you've end with two JARs in the WEB-INF/lib folder of two diferents versions. It happend to me with following the QueryViewers JARs:

- QueryViewerServicesCommon.jar
- QueryviewerServicesCommon.jar

and

- QueryViewerServicesRuntime.jar
- QueryviewerServicesRuntime.jar

That "v" uppercase/lowercase in Linux makes the files differents.